# What's the purpose of thousands of releases on all Angular bower packages?

Tags: angularjs

Why are there thousand of releases (tags) in each angular-bower-* repository?

For e.g. read the [release history of angular-bower-route](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route/releases), there are -at the moment of writing- 1,537 releases and every few hours a new one is released...

Why is this happening?

Comment: Every build creates a bower release, which allows testing the result of the build using bower.

Comment: how about using stub / off public eyes repositories for the same purpose? `angular-bower-build-route`. Current situation looks wrong any way i look at it...